# How to burn multiple sets or groups of MP3s with multiple drives simultaneously

Tags: linux, script, mp3, burning

I have lots of MP3s that I need to burn into multiple audio CDs.  I manually select 80 minutes or less of audio at a time, using multiple sessions of k3b with multiple CD-R drives to burn simultaneously.  Is there a way to automate this by writing a script using cdrecord?

Length of files may vary from couple of minutes to over 80 minutes but file names can be sorted in order.  When an MP3 exceeds over 80 minutes, the script has to pause or stop with a warning to show that it's over 80 minutes, without offering an option to overburn, before starting to burn next set or group of 80 minutes or less of MP3s with the next drive.